# Why does my cat make growling noises at night time?

Tags: cats, behavior, vocalizations

My cat makes these weird noises only at night when everyone is asleep. It sounds like a growling noise. She is the only pet in my home, she makes this growling noise when she is resting and/or asleep. She is 9 years old and she hasn’t been to the vet recently to check for any health issues. Unfortunately, I do not have any videos of her making this sound. Would anyone know why this is happening?

[image: Diamond]

Comment: A cat could make a certain noise for any number of reasons, and as it stands I think this question is impossible to provide a useful answer. Could you give a little bit more detail or context on the behaviour you are seeing? For instance, it's not clear if she is active and awake when she is making the noise, or if she is asleep? Are there other pets or animals inside or around the house? Young cat, old cat? Has she been to a vet recently to make sure she is healthy?

Comment: @HarryV. Ive updated as per your request

Comment: You could add a video if possible

Comment: a recoding of the sound and/or a video had been very helpful if i myself or somebody else should try to answer this,please try to add as much information as possible to your question.cat behaviour is very complex and is in general split into two parts,one is what they learn from their mother during the first few weeks after they are born and the other is what they learn from experience.

Comment: @Allerleirauh I do not have any videos of her making this sound. Only a recording.

Comment: @trondhansen I do have a recording, but I’m not sure how to upload it on here. I definitely do not have a video.

Comment: @LOSTinNEWYORK StackExchange only allows uploading images. For audio, you’ll need to post it somewhere like DropBox, Google Drive, OneDrive or iCloud and then paste the link here.